# Advanced regex: Can't figure a case where (?R) recursive regex can be used

Tags: regular-expression, perl, pcre

Is anyone here can explain a case where the recursive Perl/PCRE regex `(?R)` can be helpful ?

I read

- https://regular-expressions.mobi/recursebacktrack.html?wlr=1
- https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3fPARNO)-(%3f-PARNO)-(%3f%2bPARNO)-(%3fR)-(%3f0)

but still can't find a use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the tool to use to match nested structures, like nested parenthesis.
The mathematical defined regular expressions can not match this.

```
\(  ( [^()]*+ | (?R) )*  \)
```

[View it online](https://regex101.com/r/xI5KT7/1) (spaces should be ignored).

Please read:

- [Matching Balanced Constructs](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html)
- [Using Recursion to Match Palindromes (mirror words)](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html)

Comment: `perl -lne 'print $& if /\(  ( [^()]*+ | (?R) )*  \)/gmx' file` Very nice trick !

Answer (score 2):

The canonical example is matching an arithmetical expression containing numbers, operators and subexpressions in parentheses:

```
([0-9]+|\((?R)\))([-+*\/]([0-9]+|\((?R)\)))*
 ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
 number (subexp)   oper   number (subexp)
\______  _______/        \______  _______/
       \/                       \/
  One of those             One of those
                  \__________  ____________/
                             \/
                     Zero or more of those
```

that is, match

- Either a number or a subexpression in parentheses, followed by
- Zero or more times an operator and either a number or a subexpression in parentheses.